# Joint probability mass function P(N1,N2)

Tags: probability, statistics

> In a group of $6$ people, $3$ have blue eyes and $4$ have curly hair.One person has both traits. Let $N_1$ be the number of tests needed to spot blue eyes,and let $N_2$ be the number of tests needed to spot curly hair.

What I'm having difficulty in this problem is the individual events that play out for the random variables for $N_1$ and $N_2$.

How would the individual events be described per test for $N_1$ & $N_2$ characterize the probabilities?

Would the following tests be conditional upon another for the given examination?

The Answers for this question in
Having  $P(N_1,N_2)$ respectively is

Upon $P(1,1)=1/6$

$P(2,1)=(3/6)(3/5)=9/30$

$P(1,2)=(2/6)(4/6)=8/30$

$P(3,1)=(3/6)(2/5)(3/4)=3/20$

$P(1,3)=(2/6)(1/5)=2/30$

$P(4,1)=(1/2)(2/5)(1/4)=(1/20)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have:

$2$ people with **only** blue eyes (not curly hair)
$1$ person with blue eyes and curly hair
$3$ people with **only** curly hair (not blue eyes)

Let's take the case $N_1 = 2$ and $N_2=1$. When does this occur? Let's define the following events:

$A_1$ is the event where at the **first test** you get **not** blue eyes **and** curly hair. $P(A_1) = 3/6$ because we have $3$ people with curly hair but not blue eyes out of $6$.

$A_2$ is the event where at the **second test** you get blue eyes. Given $A_1$, we have now $5$ people to be tested and out of them there are $3$ with blue eyes, therefore $P(A_2 \mid A_1) = 3/5$.

Now we have

$$P(N_1=2,N_2=1) = P(A1 \cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2\mid A_1) =\frac{3}{6}\frac{3}{5}$$

The key point to note here is that when we are testing, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are counters that are both set to $0$ before the testing and are incremented at each test if the conditions for each one are satisfied.